# Angular compiler setting to specify linked .css vs inline style blocks in head?

Tags: angular, material-design

I'm using Angular Material 2 on a localhost environment. When I ng serve to view the application in a browser, I notice that there are no linked .css files (was expecting at least one - eg angular.material.css)

Instead, all of the styles are located in the head in the form of  blocks. There are literally dozens of them.

I'm ok with a few head level inline style blocks if that's the way AM2 rolls, but I'd prefer to have a single minified .css file that contains the bulk of the styling for the application.

Obvious caching advantages aside, having a linked .css also allows the entire .css file to be opened and edited in the sources tab (for debugging/testing CSS changes)

Can someone tell me if there is a global config setting that makes this happen?

Comment: are you using `angular-cli` ?

Comment: Affirmative. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

We can do all of these with  [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) by using some command

- Bundling
- Minification
- Tree shaking
- Linting
- Scaffolding (You can create new projects and generating components,services and other features)
- Build
- Serve
- -Test

You no need to do anything explicitly for the build. Everything Angular CLI will automatically take care of. They are using **Webpack** behind the scenes to do those things

If you are not using Angular-CLI , those things you have to manually do it by using some third party packages like **[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/)** or there are some other packages also available. This two packages are so popular.

Setting up those things for the build is very hard , So the Angular CLI has to be able to create an optimized build that we can deploy and perform as well.

Answer (score 0):

put all your styles in .angular-cli.json as below

```
  "prefix": "wahtever",
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "assets/codemirror/codemirror.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
```

there are 2 kinds of build

#### 1. prod --aot build

In case of prod `Ahead Of Time compilation` build it will minified and compressed to a single file called `styles.bundle.js` and will hold all your css.

#### 2. dev non aot for debug

Other is when you do `ng serve` or `ng build` it just compile and give you an option to debug in case required. Its normally used while development.